# No call stack on Exception in xCode 4

Tags: objective-c, xcode, debugging, xcode4, xcode4.2

I got an exception I can't back trace. I would like to know where the exception is thrown. Is there an option for that in xCode 4.2? As you can see the call stack is not much of a help. The only thing I know is that Iam trying to access an item in a NSArray at a faulty index.

All ideas are welcomed.
Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set a breakpoint on `objc_exception_throw` and that will stop the program on that message.

**EDIT**
... Or just set the Exception Breakpoint in Xcode. Too used to doing this stuff directly in gdb.

Comment: Thank you very much. I pressed the + in breakpoint menu. And added "Add exception break point". (On trow). Tnx