# Xcode 4 break on exception or assert with good call stack AND printing of the exception

Tags: ios, xcode, exception, gdb, lldb

Using Xcode 4.3.2.  I looked at many different similar issues including this one

[no-call-stack-on-exception-in-xcode-4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546174/no-call-stack-on-exception-in-xcode-4)

but cannot get the debugger (gdb or lldb) to give me a good stack trace that shows the location of the exception AND to also prints what the exception is

Setting either a symbolic exception on `objc_exception_throw` or an "All Exceptions" exception breakpoint, lldb would not give me a good stack trace but would show the following:

> - thread #1: tid = 0x1c03, 0x34455238 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_throw, stop reason = breakpoint 1.1
>     frame #0: 0x34455238 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_throw
>     frame #1: 0x323ff788 CoreFoundation`+[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 100

That is the whole thing, either through `bt` or at full magnification in the graphical breakpoint/debugger view.

If I hit continue a few time at this point it will eventually tell me the exception/assertion, for example

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '_endUndoGroupRemovingIfEmpty:: NSUndoManager 0x2b7610 is in invalid state, endUndoGrouping called with no matching begin

But I have no idea where it is at.

gdb, using the same breakpoint, WILL stop and show me where it is at, but does not print the exception text.  If I hit continue a few times it does but I have lost my context of the back trace.

I would like to know how to print the exception text so I know WHY it stopped, without having to do a few continues and losing my place.  I would also like to get it to stop in lldb at the point of the exception like it does in gdb.

Comment: As discussed here http://stackoverflow.com/a/1129165/792677 you can use this http://creativeinaustria.wordpress.com/2008/10/18/crash-reporter-for-iphone-applications/ and this http://creativeinaustria.wordpress.com/2008/10/20/crash-reporter-for-iphone-applications-part-2/ I'm usually getting fully symbolicated crash report which is enough to quickly solve the problem rather than play with debuggers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try updating to Xcode 4.5.  You're seeing an armv7 unwinder problem where lldb doesn't know how to unwind your stack completely.  The Objective-C runtime has some functions that are difficult to unwind out of (hand-written assembly) but I just did a quick test on an iOS device with Xcode 4.5 and lldb behaved correctly when I had Xcode set an Exception Breakpoint on throw.

Comment: I'll try that out.  Thanks!  I solved my previous code issue that had been aggravated by this problem so I will have to contrive some test cases to see how it works.  Thanks!

Comment: I've not tried Xcode 4.5 yet as I am at a critical point in a project and I don't like to mess around with my tools at such junctures.  But I have not forgotten this and will revisit once the project ends.